# rotational calculation or game's drag?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

i have a water pond, in which fishes will move to a "food", currently now im having problem making it look realistic, when a food is dropped, all fishes move to it at the same speed, and that is a kind of "drift" like a car drifting,when it is approaching a food while rotating to it. may i know what is wrong? i am thinking it is because of the drag force i have applied, but if i do not apply it, the vx and vy will add up to large amounts.

the link below contains the .swf, i have also attached the nessasry functions needed to make the fish move.
http://www.swfcabin.com/open/1310970656

```
package  
{

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.filters.DropShadowFilter;
    import flash.events.TouchEvent;
    import flash.media.Sound;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.geom.Point;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author Z
     * Fish class, makes fishes behaviors, find food.
     */
    public class Fish extends MovieClip
    { 

        //food var
        private var foodTarget:Food;
        public var foodDroppedArray:Array = new Array();
        public var foodDistArray:Array = new Array();
        private var foodInPond :int = 0;
        private var foodLocationDegrees:Number;
        //fish variables
        private var _fishSwimMax:Number = 3;
        private var _fishDrag:Number = 0.95;
        private var _fishSwimSpeed:Number;
        private var _destinationX:int;
        private var _destinationY:int;
        private var _minX:Number = 0;
        private var _minY:Number = 0;
        private var _maxX:Number = 1024;
        private var _maxY:Number = 768;
        private var _vx:Number = 0;
        private var _vy:Number = 0;
        private var _dx:Number = 0;
        private var _dy:Number = 0;
        private var foodropSound:foodSound = new foodSound();
        //global
        public var otherFishes:Array = new Array();
        public var hit :MovieClip;
        private var foodRipple:Rippler;
        private var _bg:Background;
        private var number:Number;
        private var _easeSpeed:Number;


        public function Fish() 
        {

            foodropSound = new foodSound();

            getRandomDestination();
            //fish starting settins
            this.x = _maxX/2;//Math.random();
            this.y = _maxY/2;//Math.random();
            _fishSwimSpeed = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 1000) +500;
            trace("fish speed "+_fishSwimSpeed);
            //set up shadow
            setUpShadow();

            //adding listener
            this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop, false, 0, true);


        }

        public function loop(e:Event):void
        {

            updateCollision();
            //getDistance(this.x - i.x, this.y - i.y)
            if(foodDroppedArray.length > 0)
            {
                        moveToFood(getSmallestVal(foodDroppedArray));
                        trace("moving to smallest distance of all food");
                        return;
            }else 
            {
            swimAround();
            }

        }

        /***
         * Fish to move to food with easing.
         * */
        public function moveToFood(targetFood:Food):void
        {   
            _vx += (targetFood.x - this.x)/_fishSwimSpeed;
            _vy += (targetFood.y - this.y) / _fishSwimSpeed;
            //food calculations, distance, angle etc
            var a:Number = targetFood.x - x;
            var b:Number = targetFood.y - y;
            var ang:Number = Math.atan2(b, a);
            //rotation to food 
            var foodLoc:Number = (ang * 180 / Math.PI);
            var foodFinalLoc:Number = foodLoc - rotation;
            if (foodFinalLoc > 180) foodFinalLoc -= 360;
                    else if (foodFinalLoc < -180) foodFinalLoc += 360;
            rotation += foodFinalLoc / 10;
            //acceleratin to food

            //moving towards food.
            _vx *= _fishDrag;
            _vy *= _fishDrag;
            this.x += _vx;
            this.y += _vy;
            //removing food when both hit boxes hit
            if (hit.hitTestObject(targetFood.hit))
            {
                foodropSound.play();
                foodDroppedArray.splice(foodDroppedArray.indexOf(targetFood), 1);
                targetFood.removeSelf();
            }

        }
        /**
         * Calculate Position
         */
        public function swimAround():void
        {
            //move to a random destionation point.
                _dx = this.x - _destinationX;
                _dy = this.y - _destinationY;
            // when the fish is near to the distance by * a new dest will be generated.
            if (getDistance(_dx, _dy) < 200)
            {
                getRandomDestination();

            }else {
                _vx += (_destinationX - this.x) / _fishSwimSpeed;
                _vy += (_destinationY - this.y) / _fishSwimSpeed;
                //calculation of distance to use for calculation of angle to face to
                var a:Number = _destinationX - x;
                var b:Number = _destinationY - y;
                var ang:Number = Math.atan2(b, a);

                //location to face to through the angle calculation.
                var targetLoc:Number = (ang * 180 / Math.PI);
                var finalRoc:Number = targetLoc - rotation;
                if (finalRoc > 180) finalRoc -= 360;
                    else if (finalRoc < -180) finalRoc += 360;
                rotation += finalRoc / 15;
                //apply drag then move.
                _vx *= _fishDrag;
                _vy *= _fishDrag;
                this.x += _vx;
                this.y += _vy;
            }
        }

        public function foodDropped(foodArray:Array):void 
        {
            foodDroppedArray = foodArray;
            trace("food have been dropped and lenghth is "+foodDroppedArray.length);
        }
        /**
         *Get smallest value of food distance in this array 
         */ 
        private function getSmallestVal(a:Array):Food
        {
            //we assume first food is the smallest distance between fish
            var n : Food = a[0];
            if (a.length == 1)
            {
                return a[0];
            }
            else {
                for each(var i : Food in a)
                {
                    if (getDistance(this.x - i.x , this.y - i.y) < getDistance(this.x - n.x , this.y - n.y))
                    {
                        n = i;
                    }
                }
                return n;
            }
        }
        /**
         * Get random food
         */
        private function getRandomFood():Food
        {
            var i: int = foodDroppedArray.length;
            var n : Number = Math.ceil(i * Math.random()) - 1;
            trace(" in random food "+n );
            return foodDroppedArray[n];


        }

        /**
         * Calculates a random destination based on stage size
         */
        private function getRandomDestination():void
        {

            _destinationX = (Math.random()* _maxX);

            _destinationY = (Math.random() * _maxY);

        }
        public function getDistance(delta_x:Number, delta_y:Number):Number
        {
            return Math.sqrt((delta_x*delta_x)+(delta_y*delta_y));
        }



    }

}
```

Comment: I think the problem is, that you are mixing a bunch of movement concepts together that don't really fit. Your acceleration is based on distance divided by a random number from 500-1500, which I don't really understand. If you wanted I could write a simple arrive behavior that would leave drag out during moveToFood.

Comment: hi, the division number is generated randomly, this is so to give each "Fish" a different number, by doing this i hope to give each "fish" different movement speeds.as this number is used to create a easing effect , as the fish gets closer, the _vx and _vy will get smaller value. now that you say it , im thinking its not needed? because i have *=_fishDrag. and yes if you could write one for me to see and learn from it would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be to give each fish a max speed value, use an arrive function to find the fish's desired speed vector, then normalize the vector if it is larger than max acceleration.

Applying this to your moveToFood method would look something like this:

```
// Deceleration Modifier, determines how fast a fish will slow before reaching target
static private const _DECELERATION_FACTOR:Number = 0.3;

private var _fishMaxSpeed:Number = 2;
private var _speedVector:Point = new Point();

public function moveToFood( targetFood:Food ):void
{
    // Calculate fish's desired speed with arrive behavior
    _speedVector.x = (targetFood.x - this.x) * _DECELERATION_FACTOR;
    _speedVector.y = (targetFood.y - this.y) * _DECELERATION_FACTOR;

    // Make sure speed isn't larger than fish's max speed
    if ( _speedVector.length > _fishMaxSpeed ) {
        _speedVector.normalize( _fishMaxSpeed );
    }

    //food calculations, distance, angle etc
    var a:Number = targetFood.x - x;
    var b:Number = targetFood.y - y;
    var ang:Number = Math.atan2(b, a);
    //rotation to food 
    var foodLoc:Number = (ang * 180 / Math.PI);
    var foodFinalLoc:Number = foodLoc - rotation;
    if (foodFinalLoc > 180) foodFinalLoc -= 360;
            else if (foodFinalLoc < -180) foodFinalLoc += 360;
    rotation += foodFinalLoc / 10;

    //moving towards food
    _vx = _speedVector.x;
    _vy = _speedVector.y;
    this.x += _vx;
    this.y += _vy;

    //removing food when both hit boxes hit
    if (hit.hitTestObject(targetFood.hit))
    {
        foodropSound.play();
        foodDroppedArray.splice(foodDroppedArray.indexOf(targetFood), 1);
        targetFood.removeSelf();
    }
}
```

You can modify the deceleration factor constant to get different arrive behaviours (perhaps even give each fish a different one), and you can randomize each fish's max speed as well.

Moving towards objects with acceleration is rather tricky. This solution means you would totally disregard acceleration and drag when moving towards food, which might not look great either. Perhaps a combination of this and an acceleration behavior would be the best solution.

Comment: what difference are there in a arrive and acceleration behavior? wouldnt it be the same purpose? that is moving towards something.

Comment: Well, yes, in a way. Plain arrival behavior guarantees that you are moving towards the object in question by setting the speed directly, it only dictates that you slow down when you start to get closer. An acceleration behavior cannot guarantee that, because you might be moving in the opposite or orthagonal direction when you start accelerating towards your goal. Give it a try, I added _vx and _vy to my example, you should pretty much be able to just drop that into your code and run it now.

Comment: from the both modifications i can see the difference, arrive is more of a static movement , while accelerating is literally accelerating towards the food

Comment: Watching the simulation again, there might be an even easier solution. The problem you are having seems to be that the acceleration becomes too small to overcome the drag when the fish is close to the food. You could use your acceleration method, and just add a check after that guarantees that the acceleration is always at least some minimal value. That way, you keep your behaviour and don't get that slowly creeping towards food on the final stretch. Sound interesting?

Comment: yes, you are right, when it is always near the food, it just keep getting "drifted" away some distance before moving towards the food.i will try setting a minimal value